# How get inherited attribute value in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="2c.xsl"?> 
<offers xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="2c.xsd">
    <product name="apples" xsi:type="ct_fruit_planttype">
        <harvest>May</harvest>
        <price>27.90</price>
        <supplier>Company2</supplier>
        <stone>true</stone>
    </product>
</offers>
```

How can I get `xsi:type` attribute value.

This does not work `<xsl:value-of select="@type" />`

Any suggestion please.

Comment: From what context?

Comment: I'm getting value of name attribute `<xsl:value-of select="@name" />` like that. Is it possible to get xsi:type value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If - as it seems - you are in the context of `product`, you can use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@xsi:type" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

to get `ct_fruit_planttype`.

---

Note that you can move the namespace declaration up to the root `xsl:stylesheet` element and add `exclude-result-prefixes="xsi"` in order to suppress it from the output.